# SwiftUI login with Facebook and Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, facebook, firebase-authentication, swiftui

I am trying to do a Facebook and Firebase login on SwiftUI, all right but I don't know how I can change my view when login are success

For my Facebook button, I call it like that

```
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color.gray)
                    .frame(height: 0.5)
                Text("O")
                    .font(.footnote)
                    .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color.gray)
                    .frame(height: 0.5)
            }
            .padding(.vertical, 5)
            
            VStack {
                // Apple
                AppleAuth(credentials: $credentials)
                    .hidden()
                // Facebook
                FBLogin()
                // Google
                GoogleSignInButton()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And my function for facebook login are next
Note: I can print my user token and works my button, but I don't how change to next view

```
class Coordinator: NSObject, LoginButtonDelegate {
    
    @AppStorage("logged") var logged = false
    @AppStorage("email") var email = ""
    
    func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBLoginButton, didCompleteWith result: LoginManagerLoginResult?, error: Error?) {
        if AccessToken.current != nil {
            let credential = FacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: AccessToken.current!.tokenString)
            Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (res, er) in
                if er != nil {
                    print(er?.localizedDescription as Any)
                    return
                }
            }
            print("Successs\(String(describing: AccessToken.current?.tokenString))")
        }
        if !result!.isCancelled {
            logged = true
            let request = GraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "email"])
            request.start { (_, res, _) in
                guard let profileData = res as? [String: Any] else { return }
                self.email = profileData["email"] as! String
            }
        }
    }
    
    func loginButtonDidLogOut(_ loginButton: FBLoginButton) {
        logged = false
        email = ""
        try! Auth.auth().signOut()
    }
}
```

EDIT: Solution:
If anyone needs code, a solution are next:

```
// Example of how do a login with facebook using SwiftUI and facebook login SDK

var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color.gray)
                    .frame(height: 0.5)
                Text("O")
                    .font(.footnote)
                    .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color.gray)
                    .frame(height: 0.5)
            }
            .padding(.vertical, 5)
            HStack {
                GoogleSignInButton()
                    .frame(height: 45, alignment: .center)
                    .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                SignInWithAppleButton()
                    .frame(height: 42, alignment: .center)
                    .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                Button(action: {
                    if logged {
                        manager.logOut()
                        email = ""
                        logged = false
                    } else {
                        manager.logIn(permissions: ["public_profile", "email"], from: nil) { (result, error) in
                            if error != nil {
                                print(error!.localizedDescription)
                                return
                            }
                            if !result!.isCancelled {
                                logged = true
                                let request = GraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "email"])
                                request.start { (_, res, _) in
                                    guard let profileData = res as? [String: Any] else { return }
                                    email = profileData["email"] as! String
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }, label: {
                    Text(logged ? "Login With" : "Facebook")
                        .fontWeight(.regular)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .frame(height: 45, alignment: .center)
                        .background(Color.blue)
                        .cornerRadius(8)
                })
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try passing the parent View (the screen where the button is) as a parameter into the Coordinator (ie. below @AppStorage(email) create a variable). Then access that variable and dismiss it or call a function on it.

Comment: Since that worked, I'll add this an an answer below for others to see. Please mark as correct & then we can delete these comments. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing the parent View (the screen where the button is) as a parameter into the Coordinator (ie. below @AppStorage(email) create a variable). Then access that variable and dismiss it or call a function on it.